# Why typescript throw error at useState react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm stuck at figuring out why TS throw me bunch of error although I already supplied interface to my initialState for one of my state.

can anyone help with my code below?

```
interface initialStateProps {
  eventInfo: {
    name: string;
    location: string;
  }
}

class Dashboard extends Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  //what is wrong here? ts showing bunch of error?
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<initialStateProps>({
    eventInfo: {
      name: '',
      location: ''
    }
  })

  return <div></div>

}
```

Comment: Please also share the errors you are getting. That might help us.

Comment: You should be putting those code into render method. You can not put that code directly into class like this. It has to be belonged to a method or sth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to use React Functional Components, as you are using the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook.

In that case, you should not be creating a class and extending it from `React.Component`, as those are for defining class components.

This is how you can define functional components using React and TypeScript.

```
interface initialStateProps {
  eventInfo: {
    name: string; 
    location: string;
  }
}

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<initialStateProps>({
    eventInfo: {
      name: '',
      location: ''
    }
  })

  return <div></div>

};
```

Comment: Yes, you can still use class components! But you can't use class components with react hooks, as react hooks are for functional components.

Comment: If you wanna use class components, you will have to use the usual `this.state`